# Redirect to an action in same controller in Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play 1.2.5. I have an action "welcome" which has redirect statement to an action "view1". Redirect seems to be working ( checked my log) but view of the action "view1" is not displaying after redirect.

```
  public static void welcome(){

     redirect("/view1");
  }
  public static void view1(){
   // code goes here....

  }
```

After redirect, view of view1 action is not displaying.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: why don't you run it on debug and have a breakpoint at the render instruction of your view1 method?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
redirect("/view");
```

just call

```
view1();
```

Comment: Does your `view1()` method work when accessing it directly?  Do you have the method in your `routes` file?

Comment: Yes, it is working directly. I Checked my routes file as well.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work. What happens if you call view1() from welcome()?

Comment: @emt14 when I call view1() from welcome() it is not updating and displaying view of view1

Answer (score 0):

Does your method `view1` end up with `render();` ?

If not your controller will not display anything.

You will as well need to have the correct `view1.html` file at the same level as your `welcome.html` file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply !! could you tell me what do you mean by correct view1.html file ? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, by convention if you call render() from controllers.MyController.myMethod, the view template views.MyController.myMethod.html will be used. In your example, invoking render() form view1 method will use view1.html.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your conf/routes file to ensure that view1 is exposed in a valid route matcher. For example:

```
* /view1         WhatEverYourControllerClassIsCalled.view1
```

Or via some generic matcher

```
* /{action}      WhatEverYourControllerClassIsCalled.{action}
```